# How to make the movement of cursor more smoothly in MFC?

Tags: c++, mfc, mouseevent

I am trying to move mouse cursor using Myo.

I made it but it works not perfectly.

I know that each movement of Myo moves cursor just 5 pixels in this code.

I want to improve this code to move more like real mouse.
(but not like this : point.x+500;)

Accuracy and coverage both are important.
With little movement of Myo, I want to move cursor form the left-end to right-end of monitor. (I mean 0~65535.) At the same time, I want to maintain the accuracy(for the convinience of click action).

In this code..

- compare_pitch means previous pitch_w value.
- compare_yaw means previous yaw_w value.

  ```
  if(compare_pitch < collector.pitch_w) { 
      point.y += 5; // Move Cursor Right

  }
  if(compare_pitch > collector.pitch_w)   
      point.y -= 5; // Move Cursor Left

  }
  if(compare_yaw < collector.yaw_w) {
      point.x -= 5; // Move Cursor Up

  }
  if(compare_yaw > collector.yaw_w) { 
      point.x += 5;// Move Cursor Down
  }

  SetCursorPos(point.x, point.y);
  compare_pitch = collector.pitch_w;
  compare_yaw = collector.yaw_w;
  ```

---

Below is a function for collector.pitch_w and collector.yaw_w.
(I didn't use roll_w.)

```
 // onOrientationData() is called whenever the Myo device provides its current orientation, which is represented
// as a unit quaternion.


void onOrientationData(myo::Myo* myo, uint64_t timestamp, const myo::Quaternion<float>& quat)
{
    using std::atan2;
    using std::asin;
    using std::sqrt;
    using std::max;
    using std::min;

    // Calculate Euler angles (roll, pitch, and yaw) from the unit quaternion.
    float roll = atan2(2.0f * (quat.w() * quat.x() + quat.y() * quat.z()),
                       1.0f - 2.0f * (quat.x() * quat.x() + quat.y() * quat.y()));
    float pitch = asin(max(-1.0f, min(1.0f, 2.0f * (quat.w() * quat.y() - quat.z() * quat.x()))));
    float yaw = atan2(2.0f * (quat.w() * quat.z() + quat.x() * quat.y()),
                    1.0f - 2.0f * (quat.y() * quat.y() + quat.z() * quat.z()));

    // Convert the floating point angles in radians to a scale from 0 to 100.
   roll_w = static_cast<int>((roll + (float)M_PI)/(M_PI * 2.0f) * 100);
   pitch_w = static_cast<int>((pitch + (float)M_PI/2.0f)/M_PI * 100);
   yaw_w = static_cast<int>((yaw + (float)M_PI)/(M_PI * 2.0f) * 100);
}
```

Please give me some advice. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

My Idea is to use acceleration.

Idea from my end is to use the difference `compare_pitch - collector.pitch_w` and `compare_yaw - collector.yaw_w`. If hand is moving fast, then this difference will be increased. Accelerate the change of pointer position according to this difference.

```
point.y += (int)((collector.pitch_w - compare_pitch ) * some_constant_value)
point.x += (int)((collector.yaw_w - compare_yaw) * some_constant_value)
```